# Can using UDP and OpenVPN lead to file corruption?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, tcp, udp

I know with TCP that it always checks your files to ensure nothing got fragmented or lost or destroyed.

So if I use UDP for OpenVPN to download files or access an internal network, does that mean I could end up with file corruption?

Comment: Whatever you're using to copy the file will most likely end up running over TCP over OpenVPN. You only need one TCP layer to make sure packets get there in the right order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

OpenVPN over UDP is just as reliable as OpenVPN over TCP.

Running OpenVPN over TCP is usually a bad idea, because TCP over TCP does not work well. This is because TCP expects an unreliable carrier and retransmits a packet if it times out. When the lower TCP loses a packet, it will retransmit it, but the upper TCP will also retransmit the packet, and it will queue up more retransmits than the lower TCP can handle.

The TCP over TCP problem is explained in greater detail at http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html

Answer (score 2):

in case of UDP normally the application takes care about the data integrity and error correction.

So answering your question, you shouldn't worry about underlying protocol used by OpenVPN.